# iframe full contents are not printing from IE 8 and above

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, printing

I have an iframe which renders the dynamic contents and when i print this output then the print conatins only a single page output instead of all pages.

However in print preview, it displays all the pages of iframe but in printed page i am getting only single page print and rest of the pages data is truncated.

Please help.

Code snippet:

iframe:

```
<iframe id = "form-iframe" src="some extrnal URL" width="775px" height="900px" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="margin-top: -10px; margin-left: -6px; " onload="onLoadHandler();"></iframe>
```

javascript:

```
function onLoadHandler() {
    document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = document.getElementById("form-iframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px"; 
}
```

Comment: I don't have IE8 at hands, but I'd recall there's a "Settings" tab in "Print page" window. In that tab you can see a radio button group "Print frames" (or something near that), select an option (presumably the last) to print all frames separately.